# Setting a permanent path to a static file on server

Tags: html, server

I have a static site that is built with html and css. i have a file on my server that would change every month and the name of it would change too.
i want to set a permanent address to that file that wouldn't change every time i change the file.
for example my file name is "file V1" and i want to set the URL as http://mywebsite.com/file

I managed to do this on wordpress but now my website is changed to pure html/css i don't know to do it

Comment: Can you use `.htaccess`? You might be able to use a rewrite-rule to that file if it follows a schema, like always named after the current month or so.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @PeterKrebs i did it with .htaccess file